# PyCharm not resolving packages, and not updating requirements.txt

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been tasked with updating an old python project, and so far it has been quite a frustrating experience with respect to dependencies.

I'm using Python 3.5 because it is the most recent version available in the apt repository.

The first thing I did was open up the repository in PyCharm and create a virtualenv.

I then followed [Jetbrains's instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html) for creating a `requirements.txt` file, since the project did not have one. At some point, `requirements.txt` was populated with packages, and packages were downloaded, but I don't remember when or how.

However, not all of the packages were installed. Some, such as [Faker](https://pypi.org/project/Faker/), are still underlined in red with an "Unresolved reference" error in PyCharm. When I try to use the tooltip to install the requirements, 
PyCharm installs many packages over about 30 seconds, but then ends with a `Install packages failed` error. The error says things like

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Brlapi==0.6.5 (from versions: none)
```

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Brlapi==0.6.5
```

I've tried upgrading my other dependencies to resolve this. Within PyCharm, I went to the Project Interpreter settings, which showed upgrades available for most of the packages. Upgrades succeeded for all but 2 packages (`awscli` and `python-debian`), which returned `Install packages failed` errors.

When I checked my `requirements.txt`, however, I found that PyCharm *did not* update it, even though I have set it as the "Package requirements file" under the `Settings` -> `Tools` -> `Python Integrated Tools`. Furthermore, after performing these upgrades, I get a banner across the top of the editor window asking me to "Install requirements". Doing so actually *rolls back* the project's dependencies.

What can I do to make PyCharm respect the `requirements.txt` file as the source of truth, and how can I resolve these dependency installation errors?

Comment: Do you expect PyCharm to update `requirements.txt`? It won't, IDE basically calls `pip install -r requirements.txt` and you end up with versions specified in the file assuming installation was successful. Try running the command in the terminal and track down the errors.

Comment: Yes, I expect PyCharm to update `requirements.txt`, in the same way that Eclipse updates `pom.xml` after installing packages using the UI. Does PyCharm really lack this functionality?

Comment: No, there is no such feature, feel free to create a request in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY Though not everyone will expect this behavior, I prefer to manually control what goes into `requirements.txt`.